# Safe way to remove items from an array while iterating?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, thread-safety, swift4

I have an array of closures that I would like to execute and remove each item in a safe manner.

If I simply do this:

```
array.forEach { $0() }
array.removeAll()
```

It's possible that an item snuck its way in between the `forEach` and `removeAll` execution, so I might be removing an element that didn't get executed in the previous line.

Would something like this be safer?

```
extension Array {

    mutating func removeEach(handler: @escaping (Element) -> Void) {
        enumerated().forEach { handler(remove(at: $0.offset)) }
    }
}
```

Is there a safe way to do this in an algorithmic way instead of using thread locks?

Comment: `It's possible that an item snuck its way in between the forEach and removeAll execution` No it's not, Array is a value type, so it's copied on assignment. If someone else mutated an array with the same backing storage, their array will copy the backing storage and mutate that copy, without effecting you

Comment: @Alexander while true, in practice this doesn't change the question. If `array` is a property, then between `array.forEach` and `array.removeAll`, the property may have been modified by another thread (even if `array` uses a setter to make this thread-safe), and a closure will be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I assume that `array` here is a property (otherwise the question doesn't make a lot of sense). Second, I assume that `array` is already made thread-safe. Maybe something like this, which provides synchronized access at the array level.

```
class Container {
    let arrayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "arrayQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    var _array: [() -> Void] = []
    var array: [() -> Void] {
        get {
            return arrayQueue.sync { return _array }
        }
        set {
            arrayQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._array = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that kind of system, you can make an atomic executor that clears the array:

```
func execute() {
    arrayQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        // Make a local copy of the array
        let toExecute = self._array

        // Clear the array (we have a barrier, so there's no race condition)
        self._array.removeAll()

        // async to another queue to avoid blocking access while executing
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            for closure in toExecute {
                closure()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(You mentioned "without using thread locks." You should almost never be using thread locks in Swift. That's what GCD is for, and it does a lot of work to avoid locking so you don't have to. If your goal were to do this without using GCD, then no, there is no way to safely mutate a property from multiple threads without a concurrency system of some sort, and the best concurrency system for Swift is GCD.)